# Alterar htdocs do XAMPP para pasta do pendrive (ou usar XAMPP no Pendriver)

Tags: apache, xampp

já pesquisei pra caramba, alterei tudo quanto foi linha do httpd.conf e httpd-xampp.conf mas nada deu certo.

Estou tentando alterar a pasta padrão do xampp de htdocs para uma pasta do meu pendriver, mas quando requisito localhost no navegador, é retornado:

> Acesso Proibido!
>
> Você não tem permissão para acessar o diretório requisitado. Pode não
>   existir o arquivo de índice ou o diretório pode estar protegido contra
>   leitura.
>
> Se você acredita ter encontrado um problema no servidor, por favor
>   entre em contato com o webmaster.
>
> Error 403 localhost Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.2

Alguém poderia me ajudar? (O xampp está instalado no C: do PC)

---

**Edit:**

Seguindo mais ou menos o que o @AndreMesquita disse e alguns artigos google a fora... fiz a seguinte configuração no httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "S:\Git\projeto"
<Directory "S:\Git\projeto">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    #AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    #Require all granted

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all

</Directory>
```

Ainda sem sucesso...

Comment: Altera as permissões do seu pendrive e inclui o grupo de usuário Todos com acesso completo. Não esquece de colocar as permissões no apache2.conf. Deve funcionar.

Comment: Poste como esta o VirtualHost ou o DocumentRoot dos arquivos de configuração.

Comment: @AndreMesquita, onde fica o arquivo apache2.conf?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento , seria o httpd.conf e httpd-xampp.conf ?

Comment: Isso difere muito dependente da versão ou ambiente, em Linux por exemplo os arquivos são outros, em Mac com Mamp são outros, em Mac com Apache somente é outro esquema. O esquema de arquivos vc mesmo pode configurar

Comment: Estou utilizando o windows

Comment: Independe se for windows, o esquema do Apache e arquivos de configuração é customizavel, eu realmente não uso Xampp (que é apenas um pacote como Wamp, easyphp e afins), o que entendo é de apache. No entanto o que mais achei estranho no seu problema é que o Xampp portable não funcionou pra ti. Eu acho que vc deve estar usando algum programa que esta ocupando a porta 80 (como Skype ou então tem duas instalações do Xampp e vc nem notou).

Comment: Recomendo que olhe o log do Apache, lá tem o erro completo.

Comment: Guilherme, quando utilizo a pasta padrão (htdocs, com o apache instalado no PC) funciona perfeitamente...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui! resolvi seguir a outra opção que o @RafaelSouzaCalearo deu...

Se alguem tiver com o mesmo problema que eu, (tentou instalar o xampp de várias formas) esses comandos podem ser uteis:

- **ERRO:**

> Apache Service detected with wrong path
>
> MySQL Service detected with wrong path
>
> Found Path: "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>   Expected Path: "s:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>
> Found Path: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
>   --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
>   Expected Path: s:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
>   --defaults-file=s:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

***Motivo:***

Existem serviços do xampp que não foram removidos do windows apos ser efetuado uma desinstalação

***Como corrigir:***

Excluir esses serviços que estão impedindo o xampp portable iniciar!

Abra o CMD como admin e execute:

```
sc delete nome_do_serviço
```

no meu caso eram "Apache2.4" e "mysql", depois de excluir esses serviços, reinicie o XAMPP.

- **ERRO:**

> Problem detected!
>
> Port 80 in use by "Unable to get info" with PID 7612!
>
> Port 443 in use by "Unable to get info" with PID 7612!
>
> Port 3306 in use by "Unable to get info"!

***Motivo:***

O pendrive pode ter sido removido sem finalizar os módulos e agora as portas estão sendo ocupadas por processos que o windows manteve.

***Como corrigir:***

As vezes o XAMPP mostra qual o PID do processo que está ocupando a porta, bastando finalizar esses processos com o CMD no modo administrador:

```
taskKill.exe /F /PID n_do_PID_AQUI
```

Mas as vezes ele não mostra o PID como aconteceu com o erro na porta 3306 que mostrei acima, então é necessário buscar o processo pela porta e ver qual o PID:

```
netstat -a -n -o | findstr :n_da_porta
```

O CMD irá mostrar todos os processos, basta ver o numero do PID (ultima coluna) e executar o taskKill novamente e reiniciar o XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa localizar o arquivo de configuração do apache e incluir nele:

```
<Directory K:\inetput\>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Onde, K:\inetput\ é o caminho do pendrive.

Espero que ajude. Qualquer coisa, comenta e iremos acertando a resposta.

Abs

Comment: qual o nome do arquivo?

Comment: No apache2, no linux, é apache2.conf e 000-default. O Guilherme, no comentário da pergunta falou de httpd.conf e/ou httpd-xampp.conf, mas desconheço.

Comment: estou utilizando windows

Answer (score 0):

Siga o passo a passo

1. Abra o xampp
2. Config
3. Apache httpd.conf
4. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
5. DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
6. `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">`

Ponha o diretório que deseja.